# Is there a way to have responsive content in Word? - to have content in a Window reformat/flow to window size change?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, window, libreoffice-writer

If I resize the window size of Word, is there a way to have the content be responsive? That is, the content is automatically full-width (not overflow), and the font size is automatically large enough for comfortably reading.

I know, each Word document requires us to specify page dimensions and font size. Therefore if I want to reduce the window screen and still having the text read comfortably, I need to reduce the page size and increase the font size. Assuming that I don't care about the output page and font size, it would be convenient to have the responsive feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Switch to Web or Reading view.

You can find this under the View tab. The text will size to your window. You will not be able to edit in Reading view. You may want to switch back to Print view when done.

You will not see Headers and Footers nor page separation as in Print view when in Web view..

Comment: It seems that only the Web view has responsive window. The Draft view doesn't

Comment: You were correct. I changed my answer to include Reading view.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [reading view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/read-documents-in-word-5ea57c11-94f1-4fa2-895a-bc5e6d204a81) in Word which does exactly what you need

Comment: Except, in Reading view, you cannot edit.